# List comes up as syntax error, if I delete the list it just makes the code beneath a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm fairly new to Python but I am baffled as to why this is happening, I get a syntax error on line 5 when I try to run it. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
braille_dict = {"a":"100000","b":"110000","c":"100100","d":"100110","e":"100010","f":"110100","g":"110110","h":"110010","i":"010100","j":"010110","k":"101000","l":"111000","m":"101100","n":"101110","o":"101010","p":"111100","q":"111110","r":"111010","s":"011100","t":"011110","u":"101001","v":"111001","w":"010111","x":"100100","y":"101111","z":"101011"," ":"000000"}

braille_in = list(input("Text to be translated?")
braille_out = []

def let_brai (a):
  cap_list = []
  if a.isupper() == True:
    cap_list.append("000001")
    a = a.lower()
  for k,v in braille_dict.items:
    if a == k:
      cap_list.append(v) 
      return cap_list

for x in range(len(braille_in)):
  b = let_brai(braille_in[x]
  braille_out += b

print(', '.join(braille_out)
```

Comment: Count your parentheses on the line above.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I've just kicked myself.

Comment: Also, side-note, you forgot to call the `items` method of `braille_dict`. And `a.isupper() == True` is frowned on, just test `a.isupper()`. You should almost never be testing against `True`/`False`, since it makes "truthy" stuff act falsy, and anything that is actually `True` or `False` didn't need to waste time on comparing anyway.